# How to listen change and then perform the action in RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

```
 public Flowable<ViewModel> perform(
            Flowable<PaginationParam> paginationSource) {
        return Flowable.combineLatest(
                        mConnectionState.getConnectionState(),
                        mSessionInfo,
                        paginationSource,
                        Holder::combine)
                .flatMap(this::toViewModel); 
}
```

Now I want to start perform() when I am  on the second page 
so my point is listen Pagination change and when it is not the first page(0) then call call perform().

```
final Flowable<PaginationParam > paginationSource =
                mPagination.observe(this).filter(it -> it.getOffset() != 0);
```

I don't know how can I combine these.?

Comment: What is `pagination.observe()`?

Comment: Observes "onLoadMore()" from {ScrollListener} and emits {PaginationParam}  when event happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change you `perform` function:

```
public Flowable<ViewModel> perform(PaginationParam paginationParam) {
    return Flowable.combineLatest(
                    mConnectionState.getConnectionState(),
                    mSessionInfo,
                    {state, info -> Holder.combine(state, info, paginationParam)})
            .flatMap(this::toViewModel);
```

}

and than use it:

```
paginationSource.flatMap( it -> perform(it))
            .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perform(paginationSource)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(viewModel -> {
 // doAction
}, ex-> {
 // Error
}, ()-> {
 // Completed, will not emit new action
})
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps.